# How to return/convert array value into $row in CodeIgniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model, filter

I want to convert my array value into $row in CodeIgniter, result of Array()

```
$info[] =array('name'=>$row['name']);
Example : Array ( [name] => AA01) and more...20 records
```

and then i use them into Model, to create a query filter in Model

```
$data['filter_list'] = $this->modeltype_model->getAssignedFilter($info);
```

My Model

```
function getAssignedFilter($info)
{
    $sql = "SELECT name, type, color FROM cars "
            . "WHERE deleted=0 "
            . "AND name IN "
            . "(SELECT type FROM color_cars WHERE name_type='"
            . $info . "')"; // $info , must row value

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query;      
}
```

How CodeIgniter can handle this problem ? Any suggestion ?

Thanks 
MRizq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$info[] = "'".$row['name']."'";
$filter= implode(",",$info);
```

then

```
$data['filter_list'] = $this->modeltype_model->getAssignedFilter($filter);
```

Model

```
function getAssignedFilter($filter){
    $sql = "SELECT name, type, color FROM cars 
                WHERE deleted=0 
                AND name IN 
                (SELECT type FROM color_cars WHERE name_type IN ($filter))";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query;      
}
```